# case where code never gets to clear()

Tags: java

```
try {
    if (check) {
        while (true) ;
    } else {
        System.exit(1);
    }
} finally {
    clear();
}
```

Q: Is there a case where `clear()` never gets executed? 
I personally feel that there are no cases where clear() will not be executed.

Comment: Do you mean, there are *no more cases* where clear() will not be executed? What is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

System.exit(1) prevents the finally clause from running.

Basically a finally block is executed after a try/catch regardless if the try or the catch returned normally or exceptionally.

A System.exit however prevents the block from returning at all.

while(true) ; will obviously block indefinitely. just assumed that the while (true) ; was a stub for something that made more sense :)

Comment: -1 System.exit can throw an exception, resulting in `finally` being called

Answer (score 4):

If `System.exit` succeeds, the `clear()` will not be executed. However, [`System.exit(1)` *could* throw `SecurityException` exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29), in which case `clear()` will be executed.

Comment: Is your System.exit() throwing suggestion based upon experience, or merely a theoretical possibility ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew It is based on the Java documentation; I've never seen it happen, but I always run Java in full-trust environments.

Comment: A `SecurityManager` can turn a System.exit() into throwing an Error or Exception.

Answer (score 1):

If `check` is true, then you are stuck in an infinite loop, in which case you never technically get to the finally block.

Else if `check` is false, then `System.exit(1);` is executed and your program terminates; in which case it never gets to the `finally` block to execute `clear()`.

In this example, it is actually not possible to reach `clear()`

Comment: if check is true, clear() will not be called either.

Answer (score 0):

clear will only be executed when the try block completes.

If `check` is true then the while(true) will sit there forever so never leave the try block

If `check` is false the `System.exit(0)` will just exit the program so the finally block will not run then either. But `System.exit(int)` can throw a `SecurityException` which would then cause the finally to be called.

So in summary I think it can be called if `System.exit` throws a `SecurityException`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a case where clear() never gets executed?

The two examples you have given, this is the case as you can confirm by running the code.

When you have an infinite loop, nothing is executed after it.

When System.exit() is successful, it stops the thread immediately.